# Noisy Maytag laundry machine when spinning

Tags: washing-machine, noise

My front-loading Maytag washer is making noise during its spin cycle. The noise sounds like loose objects within the washer. I balanced the washer but the noise remains. What can I do to repair this?

Comment: Could you define what you mean by your having "balanced the washer"?

Comment: Have you checked for loose change? My machine actually stores loose change in a pump catch, I know it is full when the water no longer drains from the machine!!!